# C++ Exception Not being caught

Tags: c++, exception

Im attempting to throw an EmptyListException when my linked list is empty, but the program keeps terminating if i uncomment the throw EmptyListException().
this is my EmptyListException header

```
#ifndef EMPTYLISTEXCEPTION_H
#define EMPTYLISTEXCEPTION_H

#include <stdexcept>
using std::out_of_range;
class EmptyListException : public out_of_range
{
    public:
        EmptyListException(): out_of_range("Empty List!\n") {}

};

#endif // EMPTYLISTEXCEPTION_H
```

-- Throw command in Clist.h

```
template <typename E>
E Clist<E>::Remove() throw()
{
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        cout << "Empty List, no removal";
        //throw EmptyListException();
        return '.';
    }
        ... code
}
```

-- catch in Main

```
try{
    cout << list->Remove() << endl;
} catch(EmptyListException &emptyList)
{
    cout << "Caught :";
    cout << emptyList.what() << endl;
}
```

The error 'This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Comment: Why `return '.';`? E not have to be char.

Comment: Try removing `throw()` from the definition of `Remove()`.

Comment: return '.'; i just want to end the function, i wanted to send back an empty data type. Usually this function returns the removed node data

Comment: @Eric you could use `return E()` for that.

Comment: Please rollback your edit so the question does not contain the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you told the compiler that you will not throw any exceptions from your `Remove()`! When you violate this promise it terminates the program. Get rid of `throw()` in the function declaration and try again.

Answer (score 3):

That `throw()` in the signature of your `Remove` function is a promise to the compiler that you will not be throwing anything in that function.  You need to remove that if you're going to throw anything from inside.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `throw` specifier is... special.

Normally, it is suppose to be used to precise the list of exceptions that the function might return (with inheritance working as usual):

```
void func() throw(Ex1, Ex2, std::bad_alloc);
```

When used without an empty exception list, it therefore indicates that this method will *never* throw. Should it throw, then the runtime will call `std::terminate` immediately, which by default will just terminate the program.

In general, you should not use exceptions specifications.

*Note: C++11 introduced the `noexcept` keyword to indicate that a function never throws, it's much more intuitive...*